# Display flex with flex-wrap is wrap and also with flex-shrink

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I need to do suitable css for: creating a boxes that can be splitted to one or more columns depend on the screen size. (for example: if I have 7 boxes it can appear in big screen in 7 columns and 1 row, or it can appear in smaller screen in 2 rows and 4 columns, and etc.

Now I am doing in the div container:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

and in the box class:

```
height: 166px;
width: 320px;
```

I want that if I have a small screen and I have enough place to only one column, for example: if the div parent have 600 px width, I will have just one column of boxes but a lot of extra space, I will want that the boxes will shrink in that case to width 250px (minimum width), and that I will have 2 columns..

I want to use flex-shrink only when I have one column that created from the display flex.

How can I do it? (I want it to work in all browsers, that is why I didn't use grid)

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: use *media queries* ?

Comment: I know media queries,  but I though there is a way to do it without media queries... do you know a way?

Comment: on question - as you increase the screen width you'll have this *whitespace* just before each new box comes to the first line - how do you want to handle that?

Comment: I want to shrink the width of the boxes **only when there is just one column, and there is enough place for two columns**. When the screen width is increasing I want it o go back to the initial width (350px)...

Comment: *" there is a way to do it without media queries."* - No, there isn't unfortunately. I suggest you re-think.

Comment: @RoG is there any particular reason why you are avoiding media queries? It's the perfect solution to your problem and were specifically created to solve problems like this.

Comment: Thanks! if there is no other way, I will use media queries.